# How to wait for a recurisvie function to complete in typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion, callback

I have written a program to De-serialize a binary tree into a string.

```
let serializedTreeString: string = '';
class BinaryTreeNode {
    _val: number;
    _left: BinaryTreeNode;
    _right: BinaryTreeNode;
    constructor(val: number, left: BinaryTreeNode = null, right: BinaryTreeNode = null) {
        this._val = val;
        this._left = left;
        this._right = right;

    }
}

function _serialize(current: BinaryTreeNode) {
    if (current === null) {
        serializedTreeString = serializedTreeString.concat('-1,');
    } else {
        serializedTreeString = serializedTreeString.concat(current._val + ',');
        _serialize(current._left);
        _serialize(current._right);
    }
}

function serialize(current: BinaryTreeNode) {
    let serializedTreeString: string = '';
    _serialize(current);
    console.log(serializedTreeString);
}

let root: BinaryTreeNode = new BinaryTreeNode(20, new BinaryTreeNode(8, new BinaryTreeNode(4), new BinaryTreeNode(12, new BinaryTreeNode(10), new BinaryTreeNode(14))), new BinaryTreeNode(22));
serialize(root);
```

When i print the serializedTreeString its blank as java script is asynchronous. I could use a counter, which would increase on every call of _serialize and decrease inside _serialize. This way i can check if the counter has reached 0 and print the value of serializedTreeString. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an empty string not because javascript is async (all calls in your example are sync). It is because you are shadowing outer variable definition inside `serialize`. Just remove `let` in front of `serializedTreeString`:

```js
function serialize(current: BinaryTreeNode) {
    serializedTreeString = '';
    _serialize(current);
    console.log(serializedTreeString);
}
```

In general though it is best to avoid global variables in such cases and use return instead:

```js
class BinaryTreeNode {
    _val: number;
    _left: BinaryTreeNode;
    _right: BinaryTreeNode;
    constructor(val: number, left: BinaryTreeNode = null, right: BinaryTreeNode = null) {
        this._val = val;
        this._left = left;
        this._right = right;

    }
}

function serialize(current: BinaryTreeNode): string {
    if (current === null) {
        return "-1,";
    } else {
        return `${current._val},${serialize(current._left)}${serialize(current._right)}`;
    }
}

let root: BinaryTreeNode = new BinaryTreeNode(20, new BinaryTreeNode(8, new BinaryTreeNode(4), new BinaryTreeNode(12, new BinaryTreeNode(10), new BinaryTreeNode(14))), new BinaryTreeNode(22));
console.log(serialize(root));
```